# form_valid cannot be called in Django

Tags: python, django, geodjango, formview

I followed an excellent guide (https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2016/03/26/building-a-location-aware-web-app-with-geodjango/ ) and developed an application in Django 1.9 / Python 3 which works fine.

Now I'm trying to integrate the above application in a real django project in Django 1.8 / Python 2.7. I followed again the above guide modifying the code for Django 1.8 / python 2.7.
I have an issue when I submit the data. The form_valid cannot be called. 
My models.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.PointField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    def __str__(self):
         return "%s - %s" % (self.name, self.venue.name)
```

My views.py:

```
class LookupView(FormView):
template_name = 'gigs/lookupresults.html'
form_class = LookupForm
success_url = '/'

def get(self, request):

    return render_to_response('gigs/lookup.html', RequestContext(request))

def form_valid(self, form):
    # Get data

    latitude = form.cleaned_data['latitude']
    longitude = form.cleaned_data['longitude']

    # Get today's date
    now = timezone.now()

    # Get next week's date
    next_week = now + timezone.timedelta(weeks=1)

    # Get Point
    location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)

    # Look up events
    events =  Event.objects.filter(datetime__gte=timezone.now()).filter(datetime__lte=next_week)

    # Render the template
    return render_to_response('gigs/lookupresults.html', {
        'events': events
    })
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
'my_project.gigs.views',
url(r'^$',  LookupView.as_view(), name='lookup'),
)
```

my forms.py:

```
from django.forms import Form, FloatField

class LookupForm(Form):
    latitude = FloatField()
    longitute = FloatField()
```

my first template lookup.html

```
{% extends "gigs/gigs_base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form role="form" action="/gigs/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
        <input id="id_latitude" name="latitude" type="text" class="form-control"></input>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
        <input id="id_longitude" name="longitude" type="text" class="form-control"></input>
     </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var lat = document.getElementById('id_latitude');
        var lon = document.getElementById('id_longitude');
        lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
        lon.value = position.coords.longitude;
        });
 </script>
 {% endblock %}
```

my template after submit:

```
{% extends "gigs/gigs_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
{% for event in events %}
     <li>{{ event.name }} - {{ event.venue.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run localhost:8000/gigs the template is rendered fine but when I submit the data it displays nothing.
Also when I execute the command:

```
Event.objects.filter(datetime__gte=timezone.now()).filter(datetime__lte=next_week)
```

in the django shell works fine.
I cannot figure out why my first simple app that I developed following the above guide works fine while the new integrated app not. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why are you calling `form_valid` from your `get` method? That method is called automatically after data is submitted (ie on POST) when the form actually is valid. You shouldn't call it directly at all, let alone on GET.

Comment: Are you sure the form is actually valid? Since you are not displaying form errors in your template you won't see anything if it fails validation.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely quick response @Daniel Roseman. I'm sorry, that line "self.form_valid(form)"  was one of my experiments. :-) I have removed it from my code. Also I'll edit my question.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Roseman. I 'll check if my form is valid. I think that the error will be related in Django version. Because almost the same code runs fine in Django 1.9, Python 3.

Comment: You were right ! For some reason  I had a typing mistake in the variable name: longitute in forms.py. Thus, the form was invalid and that's why form_valid could not be called. Thank you so much for  your  help !! Now I have a keyerror 'request' but I think that I'm close to solve the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind [django 1.8 is not going to be supported after 4/2018](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions), so you might want to skip to 1.11 or 2.0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

In template lookup.html you have set:

`<form role="form" action="/gigs/" method="post">`

Try changing it to:

`<form role="form" method="post">`